# positioning the table with in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have use the  following code snippet to display the data in the html table with improve the loading time with large data.

Code Snippet:

```
 <body onload="load();">
        <div id="Grid" style="overflow:scroll; width:600px;height:300px;   onscroll="handleScroll();"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">        



  var orderArray = [100];
    var viewportH = 300;
    var prevScrollTop = 0;
    var scrollTop = 0;
    var vScrollDir = 1;
    var rows = [];
    var top=0;
    var temp=0;
    var m = 0;
    var prevRenderedRange = {}, prevVisibleRange = {};
    var renderedrange, visiblerange;
        var rows = [];  
        var extend;
        var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            orderArray[i] = { "CustomerID": i, "CustomerName": "Name" + i, "City": "City" + i }
        }
        function load() {
            var panel = document.createElement('div');
            var h = orderArray.length * 20;
            panel.style.height = h + "px";
            var table = document.createElement('table');
            table.cellSpacing = 0;
            //table.style.position = "absolute";
            table.className = "table1";
            table.appendChild(tbody);
            panel.appendChild(table);
            var element = document.getElementById("Grid");
            element.appendChild(panel);
            this.render();
        }

        function handleScroll() {
            var contentdiv = $("#Grid");
            scrollTop = contentdiv.scrollTop();          

            var vScrollDist = Math.abs(scrollTop - prevScrollTop);
            if (vScrollDist) {
                vScrollDir = prevScrollTop < scrollTop ? 1 : -1;
                this.render();
                prevScrollTop = scrollTop;
            }
        }

        function render() {            
                renderedrange = this._getRenderedRowRange();          

            var datarange = orderArray.slice(renderedrange.top, renderedrange.bottom);
                var margin = ((renderedrange.top - visiblerange.top)*20) +
                    (renderedrange.top * 20) +
                     -temp +
                    "px";
            console.log("VisibleRange: " + visiblerange.top + " " + visiblerange.bottom);
            console.log("RenderedRowRange: " + renderedrange.top + " " + renderedrange.bottom);
            console.log(margin);
            $(".table1").css({ "top": margin });
            this._render(renderedrange);                        
        }

        function _render(range) {

            if (!range)
                return;

            console.log("Top:  " + range.top + "Bottom: " + range.bottom);
            for (var i = range.top; i <= range.bottom; i++) {

                if (i > orderArray.length - 1) {
                    return;
                }
                if (rows[i] != null)
                    continue;

                var vals = orderArray[i];
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                tr.className = "rowcell";
                tr.style.height = "20px";
                tr.height = "20px"
                var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
                cell1.style.border = "0px solid black";
                cell1.textContent = vals["CustomerID"];
                cell1.style.height = "20px";
                tr.appendChild(cell1);

                var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
                cell2.style.border = "0px solid black";
                cell2.textContent = vals["CustomerName"];
                cell2.style.height = "20px";
                tr.appendChild(cell2);
                tbody.appendChild(tr);
                rows[i] = i;
            }




        }       

        function _getRenderedRowRange() {
            visiblerange = this._getVisibleRowRange();
            var range = {};
            var topIndex = visiblerange.top;
            var bottomIndex = visiblerange.bottom;
            extend = Math.round(300 / 20);
            var minExtend = 3;
            if (vScrollDir == 1) {
                topIndex -= minExtend;
                bottomIndex += extend;
            } else {
                topIndex -= (extend - minExtend);
                bottomIndex += minExtend;
            }
            topIndex = Math.max(0, topIndex);
            bottomIndex = Math.min(orderArray.length, bottomIndex);
            range = { top: topIndex, bottom: bottomIndex };            
            return range;
        }

        function _getVisibleRowRange() {
            var coeff = scrollTop / (20 * orderArray.length);
            top = (coeff * orderArray.length);
            temp = (top % 1) * 20;
            var topIndex = Math.floor(top);
            var bottomIndex = Math.ceil(this._getrowposition(scrollTop + 300));
            topIndex = Math.max(0, topIndex);
            bottomIndex = Math.min(orderArray.length, bottomIndex);
            var rang = { top: topIndex, bottom: bottomIndex };
            return rang;
        }

        function   _getrowposition  (y) {
            return Math.floor((y) / 20);
        }   


    </script>
</body>
```

In this case i have update the top margin of the table to position the table with in the div . But it did not applied correctly.

Note: this is simple example for table virtualization in my case i have replace the table with in the div

Answer (score 1):

your question is not clear after all.
Anyways, if you want to position the table inside the div, make the table position value to relative to the parent div;

```
style="position:relative;"
```

this way your table will have a relative position

Comment: Thank you for your answer , provided solution is working for me.  In that same , i have face some problem in scrolling ,we can not achieve the smooth scrolling while defining the position with top margin, i have tried to create the JS fiddle to explain this problem .but i can not create the JS Fiddle. Is there any way to achieve the smooth scrolling,  in this case table will be shake while perform scrolling (due to change the margin of the top)

Comment: I think this problem comes from your javascript code, try to return false after you finish your scrolling code, maybe that will help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried with the sugessted code return false with in the On Scroll event but still i  have the same problem. Is there any other way instead of update the top margin of the table to achieve the requiremnt?

Comment: can you send me your code, so maybe I can help you with your problem

Comment: you can use jQuery effects [jQuery Effects](http://api.jquery.com/?s=effects), that way your scroll movement would be more smooth and user friendly.